# When populating a tableview, my app crashes because it claims that a property is nil, but printing that property before I set it says it has a value

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, swift3, uisearchbar

I am searching through a database of usernames with a search bar and updating the tableview's database of User() accordingly. The search updates the array fine, but my app crashes when I the tableview tries to change its own label to the first name of the User() because it claims that firstName is nil. I know for a fact that it is not nil, though. RIGHT before it tries to update the label, I print the object's property and it prints the correct username. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code...

```
class AddFriendsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var profiles = [User]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return profiles.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? FriendCell {
        let friend = profiles[indexPath.row]
        print(friend.firstName)  //PRINTS THE USERNAME...
        cell.nameLabel.text = friend.firstName //CRASHES HERE. firstName is of type "String!"
        return cell
    }
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    DataService.dataService.REF_USERNAMES.queryOrderedByKey().queryStarting(atValue: searchText).queryEnding(atValue: searchText+"\u{f8ff}").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists() {
            var results = [User]()
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshots {
                    print(snap.key)
                    let result = User(first: "\(snap.key)", last: "s", username: "s", activeTrip: "s")
                    results.append(result)

                    if snap == snapshots.last {
                        self.profiles = results
                        print(self.profiles[0].firstName) //PRINTS CORRECT USERNAME
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    })
}  
}
```

Every time I print the data the username is there... Why does this not work?

Comment: What does the error say? Does it actually say `firstName` is the problem?

Comment: It says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and highlights that line. What else could that be?

Comment: I see by the `IBOutlet`s above that you're using Storyboards, which means `cell.nameLabel` is likely an outlet, and therefore of type `UILabel!`. I'm guessing that outlet isn't properly connected, so `nameLabel` is nil.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Remade another cell for it and it worked, good insight. If you want to reply with a real answer I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the `friend.firstName` but rather `cell.nameLabel`. `IBOutlet`s are implicitly unwrapped optionals, in this case, `UILabel!`, meaning if they aren't connected properly, they'll be `nil` and crash like you're seeing. Make sure the property is hooked up to the class and it should be fixed.